# How to correctly access elements through many-to-many relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

There is such a data structure in the database

[image]

Model Users:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
    /*
      * Model(Users) with (Group_users)
      * users - group_users
        many-to-many
   */
    public function ingroup() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group_user::class, 'group_works');
    }

  
    /*
    * Model (users) with (Group_works)
        one-to-many
    */
    public function peoples() {
        return $this->hasMany(Group_works::class);
    }
}
```

Model Group_use:

```
class Group_user extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name_group',
        'user_id',
    ];

    /*
     * Model (Group_user) with (User)
     many-to-one
    */
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }

    /*
    * Model (Group_user) with (User)
      many-to-many
    */
    public function ingroup() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_works');
    }

    /*
   * Model (Group_users) with (Group_works)
     one-to-many
   */
    public function peoples() {
        return $this->hasMany(Group_works::class);
    }

}
```

Controller code:

```
// Editor group
    public function edit(Group_user $group, Request $request) {
        $editor = Auth::user()->id;
        $users = User::query()->get();
        return view('admin.groups.edit', compact('editor', 'group', 'users'));
    }
```

Blade admin.group.edit:

```
Name group: {{ $group->name_group }}
Creator group: {{ $group->user->name }}

@foreach($users as $user)
  Code User: {{$user->id}}
  Name User: {{$user->name}}
  <?php if ($user->ingroup->id == $group->id) {?> User in a Group <?}?>
 @endforeach
```

As a result, the error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

How to correctly check if a user belongs to a group using the presented associations?

Tried connecting models through existing links.

Comment: Take a look at the eloquent Docs on the Laravel website or watch one of the excellent video introductions on the web such as Laracasts -  ithink their basic Laravel is free.  Belongs to many will return a Collection not a model.

Comment: By the way it may be easier to contextually understand your diagram if you don't draw the pivot table at all and instead say there's a M:N relationship between users and groups (user member of group?) and another 1:N relationship between users and groups (user owner of group?). When drawn this way the pivot table is an implied consequence of the M:N relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the id property on a collection of users ($user->ingroup). The ingroup relationship is many-to-many, so it returns a collection of users, not a single user.

```
Name group: {{ $group->name_group }}
Creator group: {{ $group->user->name }}

@foreach($users as $user)
  Code User: {{$user->id}}
  Name User: {{$user->name}}
  <?php if ($user->ingroup->contains('id', $group->id)) {?> User in a Group <?}?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: @IntegralAL no issues. i am glad my answer solved your problem

Comment: Where can I read about it in the documentation? I'm about "contains". <? if ($user->ingroup->contains('id', $group->id) ... ?>

Comment: @IntegralAL contain is a collection method, you can read it from here 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-contains